# divs side by side with space between

Tags: html, asp.net

Why is it so difficult to have two divs side by side with little space between them?

I have tried

```
  <div style="height: 160px; width: 100%; box-sizing:border-box; display:table;">

            <div class="introwrapper" style="height:100%;    width:25%;display:table-cell;background: pink;box-sizing: border-box;">First      Div</div>
<div style="width:5%;">
 </div>
           <div class="introwrapper" style="height:100%; width:25%;display:table-cell; background: blue; box-sizing: border-box;">second div</div>

        </div>
```

But I cannot get a space between.
Its been all over SO and other blogs but none has right solution.

Comment: use float:left on the div styles to align side by side;

Comment: I finally ended up with table and tr and tds. Divs aren't always to easy. I am working on showing Radial gauges on divs and so it is very tough to adjust spaces

Comment: but if I find some good solution I would love to comeback to divs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to use `float:left` to align two DIVs side by side

```
<div style="height: 160px; width: 100%; box-sizing:border-box; display:table;">
    <div class="introwrapper" style="float:left;margin-right:30px; height:100%;    width:25%;display:table-cell;background: pink;box-sizing: border-box;">First      Div</div>
    <div class="introwrapper" style="float:left;height:100%; width:25%;display:table-cell; background: blue; box-sizing: border-box;">second div</div>
    <br style="clear:left" />
</div>
```